# Graph API POST request to scrape fails intermittently

Tags: c#, facebook, async-await, facebook-opengraph

My organization runs a news site that requests that Facebook scrape our content via our publishing process. This request is sent to the graph API via a batch of requests. The batch contains a URL for each posted article along with the HTTP method set to POST.

The request always seems to return a 200 OK, but the content is not always correctly scraped by Facebook. This is evidence by a user clicking the share button for an article on the front-end of our app. The Facebook share dialog shows
outdated or default values. The correct values should reflect our Open Graph meta tags.

The only way to remedy this reliably has been to use the Facebook sharing debugger to re-scrape the content which seems to work every time.

A developer at Facebook suggested that the problem was with our implementation which is the following:

```
private static async Task RefreshFacebookCacheAsync(IList<string> newsReleaseUris, CancellationToken token)
        {
            string appId = "our-app-id";
            string appSecret = "our-app-secret";

            bool newsSiteIsNotAccessibleFromFacebook = string.IsNullOrEmpty(appId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(appSecret);
            if (newsSiteIsNotAccessibleFromFacebook)
            {
                // removed for brevity...
            }

            string graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/?access_token" + $"{appId}|{appSecret}";

            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {
                // set the accept type and create the batch operations
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var requests = newsReleaseUris.Select(u => new { method = "POST", relative_url = $"?id={u}&scrape=true" }).ToList();
                var serializedRequests = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requests);

                // encode the batch operations
                var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "batch", serializedRequests }
                };

                // send the request and wait for the response
                response = await client.PostAsync(graphUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(queryParams), token);
                var reply = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
            {
                // logging code goes here
            }
        }

// Calling code for this method:

await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.CancelAfter(60000);
            await RefreshFacebookCacheAsync(releaseUris, cts.Token);

            cts = null;
        });
```

EDIT:

Here is the response from Facebook with details remove from the body of the response:

```
[
    {
        "code": 200,
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                "value": "*"
            },
            {
                "name": "Strict-Transport-Security",
                "value": "max-age=15552000; preload"
            },
            {
                "name": "Expires",
                "value": "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Facebook-API-Version",
                "value": "v2.12"
            },
            {
                "name": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
            },
            {
                "name": "Vary",
                "value": "Accept-Encoding"
            },
            {
                "name": "Pragma",
                "value": "no-cache"
            }
        ],
        "body": "{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/news.gov.bc.ca\\/releases\\/2017PREM0002-000050\",\"type\":\"article\",\"title\":\"Five conditions secure coastal protection and economic benefits for all British Columbians\",\"image\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/farm1.staticflickr.com\\/376\\/31446050403_570a0f0cac_b.jpg\"}],\"description\":\"Following the Trudeau government\\u2019s approval of Kinder Morgan\\u2019s Trans Mountain Pipeline Project, the Province\\u2019s clear, consistent and principled position on its five conditions has resulted in tangible and significant investments that will protect British Columbia\\u2019s environmental and economic interests.\",\"updated_time\":\"2018-02-19T17:08:49+0000\",\"pages\":[{\"name\":\"Government of British Columbia\",\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/BCProvincialGovernment\\/\"}]}"
    }
]
```

Comment: `"https://graph.facebook.com/?access_token" + $"{appId}|{appSecret}"`. shouldn;t there be an `=` after `access_token`?

Comment: If you're reusing your `HttpClient` instance for many calls (as you should), `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(...)` is going to be accumulating an extra Accept header (which will be added to all the requests it sends) each time you call this method.  If you want that header on all calls, just add it once for its lifetime; otherwise add the header to an `HttpRequestMessage` instead.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Correct, but its in our production code, just missing here for some reason.

Comment: How many of those requests are you batching? Is your system able to handle a larger number of requests, that might be made by Facebook in a very short amount of time in such a situation? What does the actual response contain, apart from the 200 status code, which data (if any) do you get shown as the scrape results?

Comment: @CBroe we don't have a large number of requests for scraping, in the past we've seen about a maximum of 60 in a single day, but usually far less. These requests are also typically not all being sent at the same time, so a batch typically won't contain a large number of requests. As far as load, our site currently sees a few thousand hits a day. I'll include the body in the response above.

Comment: That body content, does that match the OG data you expect to see?

Comment: @CBroe it does match my expectations.

Comment: If the same client tried to share the URL before, then I'd say it's likely a client-side issue. If not - make sure you have no Like button embedded on an admin-only preview mode under the same URL or something like that - that could trigger a first scrape already, before you have the article even published.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but we're seeing the same issue even in our dev environment where the developer is the only client accessing some of the URL's for the content they've created for the first time. And we also don't have a preview mode, drafts can be either viewed as PDFs or sent as emails. Sending via email sends the content as a plain text email. But thanks again!

Comment: @CBroe I looks like the request doesn't always get sent from the Facebook crawler after we send the API request, the only thing that seems to reliably do so is to use the Facebook debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was down to a timing issue in our software. Facebook was scraping outdated information because of a slight delay in our publish process and the timing of our API request.